# Links not working in IE8

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, menuitem, virtuemart

I have this page, which works fine in every other browser than IE: http://www.portable-shade.com/products.html

The problem is the thumbnails aren't clicking through.

Anyone have an idea why not? It's a Virtuemart menu item, but it's not working in IE8.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: DebugBar seems to say that your document in interpreted in IE7 Mode. You could try using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` at beginning of page to force IE to use newest rendering engine. You can type in address bar `javascript:alert(document.documentMode);` to check which version of IE is used. Also, Microsoft gives few informations about this on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks so much, it seems the compatibility plugin in Joomla was disabling the links in a weird way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned off IE8 compatibility plugin in Joomla, and that solved it.

Thanks to GlitchMr